# Why is my Backbone / Marionette App rendering before event binding is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, marionette

I am developing a Backbone.js - Marionette.js app. At the present stage, the app pretty complex, I mean, it has lots of modules and views, and many DOM objects (menus, etc) are provided by Jquery-dependant libraries.   The App is working great, but there is one big problem: if you click a button or something, right after the app is shown, nothing will happen, you have to wait a couple of seconds, and the start using the app. This only happens when testing remotely, on my local server it almost doesn't.

Is there a way to prevent the app from rendering in the browser, before every event - either declared in the marionette view or in an external library - has been binded  ?

P.D.  My guess is that the problem is caused by the external libraries, since they are called on the onShow event of the view, so although the view has been shown, the libraries didn't have time to fully load and bind the events.

Comment: Are you using a module loader, like RequireJS? Have you tried dropping a break point inside the `onShow` callback and confirm if the vendor script is present/in scope?

Comment: @seebiscuit well, everything seems to be in scope because it works, the problem is that it takes a couple of seconds

Comment: You may want to use `https://github.com/marionettejs/marionette.inspector` /or chrome extension `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/marionette-inspector/fbgfjlockdhidoaempmjcddibjklhpka?hl=en` to check what is missing after page load.

Comment: If you don't use a module loader, you're going to have to come up with your own way of detecting when your vendor scripts are loaded, OR load all your scripts synchronously...

Comment: If your external scripts are loading via HTML script tags and you don't set the `async` attribute, AND you place your Backbone code after these scripts, then all of these scripts should be available by the time you fire your app. If you're lazy loading via JS you can detect when the scripts load using the `onload` event..

Comment: @seebiscuit you are right, we should be using Require. I tried using EnsureJS but it didn't work well

Comment: Though it is deprecated, you can use Marionette's module functionality and setup your events inside of module.start, or even without module's putting anything in app.start will guarantee Marionette has loaded and not yet rendered (though can be about to).